# SQL searching in 2 week interval from the current date

Tags: sql

I'm having trouble setting up a SQL to bring up all information 2 weeks before and after the current date.  Here is what I am currently doing:

```
Select WRK.Wrk, WRK.Client, WRK.Status, WRK.TAT, WRK.Due
From WRK
WHERE WRK.Due >= now() 
Order By WRK.Due Desc, WRK.Status Desc
```

This gets me everything due on or after the current date but when I try to add lines to indicate 2 weeks before and after the current date I get errors.

Thanks

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: As weeks are always 7 days it's a simple `BETWEEN now() -14 and now()+14`. You just have to translate `+/-14` to the syntax used by your DBMS to add/subtract days from a date/timestamp.

Comment: ANSI SQL: `current_date + interval '14' day`

Answer (score 0):

Date/time function vary significantly among databases.  The use of `now()` makes me think of MySQL.  The syntax in MySQL is:

```
where wrk.Due between date_sub(curdate(), interval 2 weeks) and date_add(curdate, interval 2 weeks)
```

Note that `between` includes the end dates, so this might be off by a day in either direction.

You can implement similar logic in other databases, but the specific functions would look different.